# Installing npm for bower on dokku

Tags: django, npm, bower, dokku

I am trying to use bower install on my Django app, which is running on a dokku image.

I've got a plugin which tries to run it on pre-deploy but it needs npm and there's no npm installed on the image.

Does anyone know how to get npm on to the image or am I going about things the wrong way here?

Comment: http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/community/clients/#nodejs-dokku-toolbelt

Comment: Not sure that really solves my problem. I can easily ssh into the dokku box and run commands. My problem is that when I deploy my app, I want bower install to run on the pre-deploy hook but it can't because npm isn't installed on the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles over this problem themselves, the answer is to use this plugin:

https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt